# What is Var(X)?

Tags: probability, covariance, variance, exponential-distribution

You have a bag full of 100 LED and 100 CFL bulbs. The lifetime of a LED light
bulb in hours is distributed as *Exp*(50000) whereas that of a CFL bulb is distributed as
*Exp*(10000). Let *X* denote the lifetime of a bulb randomly chosen from the bag. Calculate
the following:

(a) var(*X*)

I'm just not sure how to start off here. I know covariance will come into play at some point, but I just don't know how to begin this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be the lifetime of an LED, and $V$ the life of a CFL. Then 
$$E(X)=\frac{1}{2}E(U)+\frac{1}{2}E(V).$$
Now we know $E(X)$.

Next we find $E(X^2)$. This is $\frac{1}{2}E(U^2)+\frac{1}{2}E(V^2)$.

Note that by properties of the exponential we know that $E(U^2)=2(50000)^2$ and $E(V^2)=2(10000)^2$.

Now we know $E(X^2)$. Finally, $\text{Var}(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$.

Comment: why are we using a binomial instead of an exponential?

Comment: @A.Alldredge: Sorry, I meant exponential. Fixed. The variance of an exponential $W$ with mean $\mu$ is $\mu^2$, so $E(W^2)=2\mu^2$.